# 'OrderedDict' and no line breaks in the CSV file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dictionary, collections

I want to create a CSV file from another CSV file using `outFile.write(str(line))` in an iteration. But this method makes the file like:

```
OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')])OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')])OrderedDict(...
```

adding `OrderdedDict` at the beginning and with no line breaks. This should be like (**same as Input CSV**):

```
key1, key2, key3
value1, value2, value3
value1, value2, value3
...
```

The code I wrote is:

```
with open(path_to_read_csv_file, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        if [condition]:
            outFile.write(str(line))
        else:
            continue
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please add example input file. And what exactly you mean by `remake the CSV` file?

Comment: This is an example of input file:
key1, key2, key3
value1, value2, value3
value1, value2, value3
...

Comment: I'm filtering some rows and create new CSV file with the remain

Comment: Please add this into question, I am not sure if there are line breaks or not. Comments are bad place for such data :)

Comment: It is done. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DictWriter

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

data = """\
key1, key2, key3
value1, value2, value3
value1, value2, value3
"""
f = StringIO(data)
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
o = StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for d in reader:
    writer.writerow(d)

o.seek(0)
print(o.read())
```

Comment: Where what is??

Comment: Replace `outFile.write(str(line))` with `writer.writerow(line)`.

Comment: I gave you everything you need. You have to learn to find and read the python docs yourself. I wrote that using my phone and that's all I'm willing to give you today.

Comment: It is not enough that you can copy and paste code. You have to try to understand the code you are using.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html). It is good to work with when dealing with tabular data. Has many useful functions (to filter data too).

```
import pandas as pd
path_to_input_csv = 'example_csv.csv'
path_to_output_csv = 'example_csv_out.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_input_csv, sep=',', header=0)
is_ok = df['key2'] == 'good_value'
df = df[is_ok]
df.to_csv(path_to_output_csv, sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

my input file:

```
key1,key2,key3
value1a,good_value,value3a
value1b,bad_value,value3b
```

output file:

```
key1,key2,key3
value1a,good_value,value3a
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
with open(path_to_read_csv_file, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        if [condition]:
            outFile.write(str(line))
        else:
            continue
```

you are iterating over `csv_reader`, and each iteration produces a *dictionary*.  It would be better to write the output back to csv file using the csv module's tools:

```
with open(path_to_read_csv_file, "r") as csv_file, open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    # Get the column headers.
    fieldnames = list(next(csv_reader).keys())
    # rewind to the beginning of the file.
    csv_file.seek(0)
    csv_writer = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        if [condition]:
            csv_writer.write(line)
```